# JavaScript Pass Form Values to New Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

We're going to have two levels of questions for the respondents on a landing page.

On one page, they'll choose up to four interest tracks using checkboxes: check, check, check, check, click Next.

On the next page, they'll choose one option, and that's where the form submit will happen. I need to be able to capture the checkbox selections on the first page so that I can pull them into fields on the form page.

My initial thought is when the user selects a checkbox, that gets stored into an array which then passes that as query strings to the next page. That page then reads the query strings and adds it to hidden fields? Suggestions/ directions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Solution you are thinking is fine if you are planning to use JavaScript only and two different layout. If you have same layout for both pages. You can just hide and show required fields for the form conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

Query string would be your best option if the information is not a security risk then its very easy to get all your data from there.

you could do a simple one like this:

```
www.example.com/home.aspx?questiona=true
```

then you can read it using javascript

call the function on page load and pass in the name you want to break it down with i.e.

```
getQueryStringValue('questiona');

   function getQueryStringValue(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        var answer = results === null ? "" :
decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        alert(answer);
    }
```

Also you could store the data in a `cookie` which would work as well.

Also you could have it all on one page why do you need to reload the page? You can manipulate the UI every time the user clicks there answer.

The rest of the ways would mean that you would have to store it server side and get it back on your new page.

i would recommend through the query string it does the job quicker and just as good.

Answer (score 1):

@JoshStevens is correct, url parameters are likely the way to go. If that isn't an option because the data is sensitive, you could look into [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)  to store the data temporarily between pages.

Comment: yes i agree sessionStorage could be a good idea.. also a cookie would do the job as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be two pages? you can still display/hide content on one page - pull dynamic content based on initial content selection. This way you can have all your fields in a form. You would just have to selectively display the content appropriately.

```
<form>
<div id="step1">step1 content</div>
<div id="step2">step2 content</div>
</form>
```